# rule for distributing a negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that $-a(1-c)$ is the same as $a(-1+c)$ or $a(c-1)$.  In order for me to see that it was ok to write it that way, I needed to first distribute $-a$ over $(1-c)$ and after seeing the expression as $-a +ac$, I knew it was ok to factor out the $a$ write it as $a(-1+c)$.

What is the rule that allows for taking the $-1$ from the $a$ and distributing the $-1$ inside the parens directly rather than expanding and factoring out the $a$?

edit: I mistakenly used $f$ as a variable rather than a function.  Since this got the question put on hold due to ambiguity, I renamed $f$ to $a$.

Comment: Your $f$ is the symbol for a function $f(x)$? In this case there is no distribution properties for a generic function.

Comment: I apogolize for reusing $f$, in this case it's just an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a variable for a real number, you have:

$$
-f(1-c)=-1\times f\times(1-c)=f\times(-1)\times(1-c)=f(-1+c)=f(c-1)
$$

where we have used the properties of $+$ and $\times$ operations on $\mathbb{R}$: commutativity of product, distributivity and commutativity of sum.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I knew it was something like that!